# Azure CLI 2.x is not installed on this machine

Tags: azure-devops, azure-cli, azure-pipelines-yaml, azure-pipelines-tasks, azure-cli2

I'm trying to upload blobs using "az storage blob upload-batch". I got below two exceptions.

1. ##[error]Azure CLI 2.x is not installed on this machine.
2. ##[error]Script failed with error: Error: Unable to locate executable file: 'pwsh'. Please verify either the file path exists or the file can be found within a directory specified by the PATH environment variable. Also verify the file has a valid extension for an executable file.

```
    task: AzureCLI@2
    displayName: 'Upload Files'
    inputs:
      azureSubscription: 'xxxxxxx'
      scriptType: 'pscore'
      scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'
      inlineScript: |
        $subscriptionName = $(az account show --query 'name' --output tsv) 
        az storage blob upload-batch `
          --subscription $subscriptionName `
          --account-name xxxxxxxxx `
          --source "C:\xxx\yyy" `
          --destination MyContainerName `
          --auth-mode login
```

Comment: try to uninstall and install like here: https://adamtheautomator.com/install-azure-cli/

Answer (score 2):

Thank you @N MZ , Posting your suggestion as an answer to help other community members.

> ##[error]Azure CLI 2.x is not installed on this machine.

> ##[error]Script failed with error: Error: Unable to locate executable file: 'pwsh'. Please verify either the file path exists or the file
> can be found within a directory specified by the PATH environment
> variable. Also verify the file has a valid extension for an executable
> file.

For this above errors **we need to install** [**`Azure cli`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/install-azure-cli)
and check running cmd `az version` if its installed or not .

[image]

For More information please refer the below links:

- MS DOC:[Azure File Copy task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-file-copy?view=azure-devops)
- SO THREAD: [How to run Azure CLI tasks from an Azure DevOps Pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66509534/how-to-run-azure-cli-tasks-from-an-azure-devops-pipeline-on-a-self-hosted-window)
- [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/storage/blob?view=azure-cli-latest#az_storage_blob_upload)

Answer (score 2):

Although not the best approach, for a quick test, you could [install az cli](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/install-azure-cli) while running the job steps:

```yaml
jobs:
  - job: my_job
    steps:
    - script: curl -sL https://aka.ms/InstallAzureCLIDeb | sudo bash
      displayName: 'install az cli'
```