# Why is Azure cli not recognized in Azure Pipeline PowerShell task?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-cli

I installed `Azure cli` on a `Windows Server Agent` and it works fine in `cmd`/`PowerShell`. but when I want to use `Azure cli` on `PowerShell` task in `Azure Pipeline` it's not working.

the error message is: 'az' is not recognized as an internal or external command.

`cmd` example on agent:

[image]

task code sample on `Azure Pipeline`:

```
- powershell: |
        echo "*********" | az devops login --organization https://dev.azure.com/*****
  displayName: 'Login on Azure CLI
```

I check `Path` environment variable and even update variables in pipeline to ensure everything fine but nothing changes.

Comment: There is an explicit Azure CLI task in Azure Pipelines, which you could use.  Also, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66509534/how-to-run-azure-cli-tasks-from-an-azure-devops-pipeline-on-a-self-hosted-window may be relevant. Note restarting the agent service/machine is required?

Comment: Thanks for your response. I test the restart solution and it's not the answer. about AzureCLL task I try with version 2 and it's not working either. I will try version 1 and come back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have followed the below steps to execute `az` command from the azure pipeline. Check if you have followed all these steps and able to ressolve the issue.

Firstly I used the below command to install Azure CLI on a windows machine.

```
$ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'; Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://azcliprod.blob.core.windows.net/msi/azure-cli-2.49.0.msi -OutFile .\AzureCLI.msi; Start-Process msiexec.exe -Wait -ArgumentList '/I AzureCLI.msi /quiet'; Remove-Item .\AzureCLI.msi
```

Next I installed the devops agent on VM with following configuration.

[image]

When configuring the pipeline, ensure you select the correct agent pool. [In my case it is `default`.](https://i.imgur.com/iUj3D4L.png)
To test, add a [powershell task](https://i.imgur.com/dblcga6.png) task pipeline with command `az login --service-principal -u $(appid) -p $(passwd) --tenant $(tenant)`. Run the pipeline and verify the output.
[image]

If you still encounter issues, check the environment variable path to verify if the AZ CLI path is included. You can run `echo $env:PATH` from the pipeline to check.
[image]
If the AZ CLI path is not present, add it to the system variables and verify again.